# Why not just use a shared import rather than React.createContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I'm building an app and I have a class that manages websockets which I'd like to be available in every component, because a lot of them read from it. Trying to avoid passing props through countless components.

To this end I've been trying to use `React.createContext`, but I'm getting errors like this:

```
App defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.createContext().
```

There might be a fix for this, but I'm starting to wonder: why not just put the value that I want to share into a lib file, and import that file into the ones I need the shared value in? Are there any downsides to this?

Using the mobx observable/observe pattern, updates to the properties seem to still get reflected in the dom.

For example:

shared.js

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class SharedClass {
  @observable x = 1;
}

const sharedInstance = new SharedClass(1);

export {
  sharedInstance,
}
```

App.js

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { sharedInstance } from 'lib/shared';

@observer
class App extends React.Component() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    sharedInstance.x = 2;
  }

  render() {
    return <>
      The shared value is {sharedInstance.x}.

      <Stuff... eventually with a nested Page component>
    </>
  }
}
```

Page.js

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { sharedInstance } from 'lib/shared';

@observer
class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <>
      The shared value is {sharedInstance.x}.
    </>;
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is just a constant value do that. But if you want to update that value during the life of the user session, then you need to use a method that notifies the affected components that they need to re-render to use the updated value

Comment: Is that value ever going to change? If not, there's no reason to use the context for it. It's a constant, just use its value whenever you'd like.

Comment: Also note that `SharedValue = 2;` wouldn't work since you're trying to reassign a value to a `const`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron good point, thanks, was just riffing :)

Comment: The value that I want to share is a class using `@observable` values from mobx. The classes to which it is imported are themselves marked as `@observers`. The shared class does not change once initialized, but its properties may, and it seems that the observable/observer pattern still works here and page state does update when the values change.

Comment: Ok so you're asking a totally different question. You should be asking about your real use-case. A class with dynamic values is way different from a constant value.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ok, good point, thank you. I've updated the example to be closer to my real case.

Comment: One downside here is if `sharedInstance.x` changes, React doesn't know about it so it won't re-render.

Comment: That's a good point. I've added the mobx decorators, and this seems to make the state update as expected when `sharedInstance.x` changes.